# Exact Gaussian elimination of a rational matrix

Tags: computational-complexity, gaussian-elimination

If a matrix $A$ consists of rational elements, and we have access to only row operations of the form

- Row addition/subtraction from row $i$ to row $j$
- Row exchanging row $i$ with row $j$

What is the time complexity of reducing the matrix to a triangular form.

If we write the matrix as a set of fractions of the form $a_{i,j}=u_{i,j}/v_{i,j}$ where $u,v$ are integers. Then we could factor out all the denominators to be left with a matrix $A'$ of integers such that

$$A=\frac{1}{c}A'$$

where

$$c=\left(\prod_{i,j}v_{i,j}\right)$$

and each element is multiplied by $c$, i.e. $a_{i,j}'=a_{i,j}c$.

We could then perform integer Gaussian elimination [which in itself can be performed in polynomial time](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/63278/complexity-of-computing-matrix-rank-over-integers).

However, $c$ is exponential in the size of the matrix. Is there any algorithm that exists which can perform Gaussian elimination of this form in polynomial time?

Comment: The *value* of $c$ is exponential, but its *bit-length* is only polynomial. Thus this gives a polynomial-time algorithm as is.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek Ah of course!

Comment: The raw operation you describe is insufficient. One also needs row exchange operation to bring a matrix to triangular form.

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko Sorry, yes, row exchanging is also allowed